# How can i create new empty list and appending list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some problem with lists in prolog. Here is my code...

```
add(X,List,[X|List]).

append([],X,X).
append([X|Y],Z,[X|W]) :- append(Y,Z,W).

d([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
    (   H1 > 0
    ->  (   H2 > 0
        ->  write(H1), write(H2), H4 is H1 - 1,
            H5 is H2 - 1,
            H5 > 0
        ->  length(Visited, Y),
            (   Y > 0
            ->  add(H5, Visited, Visited)
            ;   add(H5, [], Visited)
            ),
            add(H4, T1, X1),
            d(X1, T2)
        ;   add(H4, T1, Z1),
            d(Z1,T2)
        ;   d([H1|T1],T2)
        )
    ;   append(Visited, [H2|T2], NewList),
        d(T1,NewList)
    ).
```

Input is: `d([3,0,2,2,0,4,1],[1,1,3,3,1,1,2])`.

Here first list is row and second list is column. My goal is to print the first element from the row and column and travel in the list. Here condition is that when i already visited element from row and column then i have to subtract that element by '1'. for example in above input first element of row is '3' and first element of column is '1' so when i picked elements from row and column then i have subtract by '1'. Therefore, final value will be [2,0,2,2,0,4,1] and [0,1,3,3,1,1,2]. Like wise i want to travel the list and. when we get column '0' then i should shift to next column same for row as well.

Here i'm doing, making column fix until it get '0' and iterating row one by one and storing the new values of row in another list but when i running the code its not printing anything. any help will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'already visited'? In your example, you subtract 1 from said elements while they're at the heads of the lists, so there's no way you had already "seen" them somewhere inside the lists.

Comment: 'already visited' means that element is already in head to so i'll print it and subtract it. After subtraction if row element is still greater than '0' then i store that element in another list for later use and make column element fix until it sets to '0'.

Comment: Your indentation-style is extremely hard to read.

Comment: @Rahul: can you rewrite the code without using `-> ;` operators, they are very *non-Prolog* and not easy to understand. Your explanation is not easy to understand.

Comment: -> ; this operators work as a if and else statement. if i remove it than how the code will work? This is the complete code.

Comment: Gah!! Don't post code in comments. If you need to add more code, please edit the original question and put it there, properly formatted. :)

Comment: Note `length(Visited, Y), (Y > 0 ->  add(H5, Visited, Visited) ; add(H5, [], Visited)),` is the same as just `add(H5, Visited, Visited)`. Instead of `add(H4, T1, X1), d(X1, T2)` you can just use, `d([H4|T1], T2)` since you don't use `X1` anywhere else. Similarly in other places. And be mindful of operator precedence: `,` before `->` before `;`. Parenthesize where needed.

Comment: I've read your "question" twice, but I don't see a question. I see a description of what you're trying to do, and then an "any help appreciated". What do you need help with? Are you encountering a specific error? Incorrect results? What have you tried to debug?

Comment: @lurker: code is not running. I'm not getting the result. Yes i tried debugging but i'm not getting. I'm new in prolog.

Comment: What does "not running" and "not getting the result" mean? Does it hang? Does it return an incorrect result? To start, read my prior comment about operator precedence and then read through your code structure again to make sure it's properly structured knowing what the precedence will do. Also, `Visited` is used in `length(Visited, Y)` but `Visited` hasn't been defined. It looks like you need an auxiliary predicate: `d(In, Out) :- d(In, [], Out).` where the 2nd argument would be your `Visited` list, and your predicate would be `d([H1|T1], Visited, [H2|T2]) :- ...`.

Comment: yes it hangs.. can't i define empty list in the beginning?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what the code is supposed to do. You can define empty list in the beginning. That's what the auxiliary predicate is for. It probably hangs partly because, `length(Visited, Y)` is being performed on an uninstantiated list, so the sky's the limit on solutions to that query. You can't assign (instantiate) a variable in a predicate clause and then change it later in the same clause without backtrack. That's how Prolog works. If you're struggling with that, you might want to tackle some simpler Prolog problems first.

Comment: Non-descriptive, one-letter predicate name? `d/2`: Check! Nested if-else constructs? `d/2`: Check! Re-definition of a library predicate? `append/3`: Check! Hiding functionality behind a new name? `add/2`: Check! Incomprehensible problem statement description? Check! No clear question at the end? Check!